# FileMaker Pro 10 - How does concurrancy work?

Tags: filemaker

I have FileMaker Server set up hosting a file for about 20 users.

I'm curious what happens if two users try to edit the same record? How about the same field?

Also is there a way to explicitly lock a record while one user is editing?  (I want to run a script to validate the record with some business rules before the user is allowed to save changes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileMaker locks whole records automatically when user tries to change them. If another user tries to change a record, he will see a message that the record is in use. In scripts you can explicitly open a record with **Open Record** script step.

In your case you probably need to use a **OnRecordCommit** trigger (or, perhaps, **OnRecordValidation** for v11). Write a script that checks the business rules and returns True or False depending on the result. Note that these are layout triggers, so you'll need to have them on every layout that can be used for editing.

Comment: thanks.  Would OnRecordCommit only fire if the user has changed the record?  That's the only time I'd want it to run.

Comment: @Greg. Well, yes and no. In normal data input scenario user can only lock a record by trying to change something. So in this case OnRecordCommit will only fire after user typed something in a field, selected a value from a list, etc. (It doesn't check if the new value is same as the old one.) But it will also fire if you, say, used Open Record in a script without changing anything, although this is an artificial scenario.